# Vim: delete to next character, when next character is not on same line

Tags: vim

I'm sure that I'm going to get ridiculed for asking a duplicate question; someone must have asked the question before!  But in an hour of searching I haven't found it.  I must be searching for the wrong thing.

In Vi (or Vim) I am able to delete all characters up to the `}` character through the key sequence `dt}` (or `df}` if I want to remove the bracket as well).

However, this only works if the `}` character is on the current line.  What I want to do is to delete everything up to the next `}` even if it's first occurrence is on a subsequent line.

I'm thinking something like `d/}` (where the slash `/}<enter>` in any other context, would take me to the next occurrence of `}`).  For obvious reasons, this doesn't work, but I hope the intention is clear.

== EDIT ==

Okay okay okay... sorry.  You're all right, it does work (on my clean-install machine).  might be some messed-up mapping in a config file, but it's not working on my other one.

*Hang head in shame*

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Because it works fine for me.

Comment: Of course I've tried it!!  And what works fine for you?

Comment: What are the "obvious reasons" that would make it fail ? What's the behavior on your vim ?

Comment: What's your version? Mine is 7.3.46, and it's possible that this wasn't available in earlier versions.

Comment: Not working for me, which configuration messed it up for you ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`d/}<cr>` works. It's the canonical way to delete until the next `}` that's not on the same line. By the way, `d?{<cr>` does the same but in the opposite direction.

Comment: What does `<cr>` mean?

Comment: `:help key-notation`

Answer (score 3):

This [plugin](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic) should save you some keystrokes. It extends the functionality of fFtT,; so they work across lines.

Answer (score 1):

If the character is `}` or `{` placed at the beginning of the line, one way could be using *Text object motions*, so a command like `d]]` could be useful too.